# Jquery (not)selector / Horizontal Accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, selector

www.brianvargo.com/test.html

I'm working on an accordion with panels of different widths - the selected panel takes up 50% of the window, then retracts to its originial width upon mouseout.

I'm now trying to make all of the other accordion panels shrink when one is selected, such that you can still see all  of the content, but the proportional relationships remain relevent. In other words, achieving an effect like this:

http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/05/horizontal-javascript-accordion-menu/

...but using the jquery dialogue I've been working on so I can maintain various panel sizes.

Any Ideas? 
www.brianvargo.com/test.html

Comment: Please edit the relevant code into your question. After you take your test page down or change it, this whole post will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code in animated-menu.js you are only animating(increasing width) of the hovered element. At the same time you also have to reduce the width of the adjacent element also so that there is enough real estate available for the element to fit within thee screen width available.

Comment: bingo. The problem is I am having trouble selecting all the other panels and telling them to reduce their width by 50% (since all of them are different)